# coxph in R: Error in if (any(infs)) warning(paste("Loglik converged before variable "

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I know this has been a similar question in another thread. However, I added the suggested solution into my code and it still didn't work:

```
output<-coxph(Surv(start, timepoint, progress) ~ DMT + DMT:timepoint + 
+ dens + cluster(pair), weights=weight, robust=TRUE, data=input)
```

And the error message is:

```
Error in if (any(infs)) warning(paste("Loglik converged before variable ", : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I don't want to confuse people now, so if you need more information, let me know, maybe a summary of the input data file ?! I just have absolutely no idea what could be the reason for this error.

Thank you for any help,
highly appreciated !

best regards